# Is it possible to use two laptops as dual display monitors in the same X Session?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, ssh, xserver, remote-x-session

Picture this :

You have two identicle laptops. Both running Ubuntu with X11. Now rather than having two seperate ubuntu machines is it possible, through XServer, to connect Laptop2 to Laptop1 as a second display that runs in the same session as Laptop1?

Basically I want to be able to replicate the effect of plugging in an external VGA monitor to Laptop1 with Laptop2.

I know there are programs like Synergy to act as a virtual KVM between two machines. But you still have two seperate systems with seperate displays and programs and such.

I know you could use VNC to get laptop1's display on laptop2, but then you have the opposite effect of having one display with two mice and keyboard, on two monitors.

Aside from the issues with those solutions, I'm trying to do this without too much bloat, and I know XServer has remote capabilities, but I don't yet have the knowledge to implement what I'm trying to do.

I'm looking for either specific ways to do this or references to specific documentation to help me implement this.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this, because there is no way to connect the screen on the second laptop to the video output of the first.

Answer (score 1):

Actually after doing some more serious digging I found that the xdmx project serves all my needs. It uses a proxy x server to connect multiple x servers on seperate machines.